# Why the change of the widget inside the get_form method does not reflect the change in the Django admin site

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

#### What I want to do:

Show a widget of type `forms.widget.FileInput` in my admin site but in the model have a field of    type `model.TextField`.

**models.py**:

```py
    from django.db import models


    class Post(models.Model):
       image_in_base64 = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

**admin.py**:

```py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.forms.widgets import FileInput
    from .models import Post

    class MyAdminPost(admin.ModelAdmin):

        def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
            form = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
            form[Post._meta.fields[-1].name].label = 'Main image of the post'
            form[Post._meta.fields[-1].name].widget = FileInput()
            return form


    admin.site.register(Post, MyAdminPost)
```

The input in the panel is still of type text, why?

Comment: `form[Post._meta.fields[-1]` is not syntactically valid: there should be two closing brackets.

Comment: Reason is quite likely that the form is initialized already, and thus the widget has a deep copy in the "concrete fields".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is likely to specify a form with:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {'image_in_base64 ': 'Main image of the post'}
        widgets = {'image_in_base64': forms.FileInput()}
```

and then plug this into the `ModelAdmin`:

```
from django.contrib import admin


class MyAdminPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostForm
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. For newbies like me, the Meta class should have: `fields = '__all__'`

Comment: @Nedo: aarrggghhh, thanks!